# Se puede hacer un FOR dentro de un ALERT?

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, alert

lo que pasa es que quiero mostrar datos hechos con un **for** dentro de un solo mensaje de **alert**, ya he intentado de todo pero no he logrado nada, y ni siquiera se si es posible hacer eso.

Comment: No se puede, lo que puede hacer es el en `for` concatenar todo el string y luego mostrar en el alert.

Comment: Una alternativa es usar `console.log` Asi dentro del for vas imprimiendo lo que pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya mencionaron, no puedes hacer un `for` dentro de `alert`, pero sí puedes crear el string que deseas usando un `for` y luego hacerle un `alert` a ese string. Te muestro dos ejemplos de esto:

Primer ejemplo:

```js
let mensaje = '';
for (let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    mensaje += 'comentario numero ' + i + '\n';
}
alert(mensaje);
```

Segundo ejemplo:

```js
let mensaje = '';
let comentarios = ['primer comentario' , 'segundo comentario', 'tercer comentario'];
comentarios.forEach(com => {
    mensaje += com + '\n';
});
alert(mensaje);
```

Comment: puedes hacer que se pueda ejecutar el código? es que a mi no me sale el botón de "Ejecutar" ni los otros

Comment: Ya está hecho, espero que ayude

Answer (score 0):

para poder mostrar datos según lo que mencionas, debes hacer dentro del for que estos datos se vayan guardando en una variable, del tipo correspondiente ya sea texto por ejemplo, y esta variable llamarla en el alert, te muestro un ejemplo básico en Javascript.

```js
var mensaje = "Numeros: ";
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  mensaje = mensaje+ i;
}

alert("VARIABLE MENSAJE CONTIENE = "+mensaje);
```

Es un ejemplo sencillo, si tienes dudas me avisas amigo.